# Освобождение ресурсов java

Tags: java, resources, filewriter

хотел узнать такой момент, если к примеру у нас есть такой код

```
FileWriter w1 = new FileWriter("...");
FileWriter w2 = w1;

w2.close();
```

В этом примере будут ли доступны ресурсы по ссылке w1 или то, что я освобождаю их через ссылку w2 приводит к их полному освобождению для всех ссылок?

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы присваиваете переменной `w2` ту же ссылку, что и `w1` - они указывают на один и тот же объект. Любые действия и через `w1`, и через `w2` - работают с одним и тем же с объектом.

---

Следовательно `w2.close();` приведёт к тому же, что мог бы сделать `w1.close();`.

Вот и получается  поток вывода закрыт, через него больше нельзя взаимодействовать с файлом (и конечно через `w1` закрывать уже нельзя, т.к. поток уже закрыт через `w2`).

---

Но если вы сделаете:

```java
obj2 = obj1.clone()
```

то действия по ссылке `obj2` не будут отражаться на объекте по ссылке `obj1`, т.к. это два одинаковых (на момент создания), но самостоятельных объекта.

---

---

Ссылка это просто указатель на область памяти, в которой находится объект. Объект удаляется, только если нет **ни одной ссылки**, указывающей на него и требуется дополнительная память. И если объект удалён, следовательно и ссылки на него больше нет. Так что выражение:

> приводит к полному освобождению для всех ссылок

не верно.

---

Если объект вам не нужен - присвойте ссылке на него `null`, и тогда его удалит сборщик мусора. Так же к удалению объекта приведёт выход программы из его области видимости. Но так можно делать не всегда, в примере с теми же файлами нужно сначала файл закрыть, а потом удалять объект.

---

И последнее:

Не забывайте, что объект удаляется тогда, когда система сборки мусора посчитает это нужным.

И если вы сделаете что-то вроде:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) 
    SomeObject obj = new SomeObject()
```

на время выполнения цикла и некоторое время после него старые объекты могут занимать много памяти.

Comment: Не лишним будет отметить, что `clone()` можно не у всех объектов вызвать (например у `FileWriter` нельзя).